# Neo4j list NOT IN another list query

Tags: neo4j

The `Person` and `Restaurant` nodes have `(:Person)-[:LIKED]->(:Restaurant)` type of relationship. A person may like many restaurants.

The `Restaurant` and `City` nodes have `(:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(:City)` type of relationship. A restaurant may be located in more than one city.

The `Person` and `City` nodes have `(:Person)-[:LIVES_IN]->(:City)` type of relationship. A person may live in more that one city.

I want the `person_name` who likes a `restaurant` that is located in a `city` that is different from where they live right now and the list of such restaurants and here is my attempt:

```
MATCH (c:City)<-[LIVES_IN]-(p:Person)-[:LIKED]->(r:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(rc:City)
WHERE NOT c.city_name IN rc.city_name
RETURN p.person_name, collect(r.restaurant_name);
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (c:City)<-[LIVES_IN]-(p:Person)
WITH p, COLLECT(DISTINCT c) AS personCities
MATCH (p)-[:LIKED]->(r:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(rc:City)
WHERE NOT rc IN personCities
RETURN p.person_name, collect(r.restaurant_name)
```